# Oscilloscope to Function Generator Trigger Delay

Tags: oscilloscope, function-generator, trigger

Simple question, is it common for there to be a delay between an external trigger out from an oscilloscope to the trigger in of a function generator?

Specifically, I have a Rigol 1054Z oscilloscope and a Rigol DG1022 function generator. The oscope is measuring a signal for a rising edge trigger, the trigger out signal is connected to my function generator via a BNC. My function generator is set to be a pulse for 350ns configured in burst mode with an external trigger. This output is connected to a T junction with one side connected to a Max chip and the other to a BNC connected back to my oscope. I'm measuring ~750ns of delay from when my trigger fires to when the function generator outputs. Is this normal? Is there some setting that could improve it? I tried looking in the datasheets but I do not see anything mentioning the external triggers and some delay except maybe some 10ns or less fields.

[image]
Yellow=Control, Purple=Signal from generator, Blue=Output of Max chip.

Any hint as to this being normal or not would greatly help thank you.

Comment: Good question. It seems like the delay of 750ns is both because of the propagation delay as well as the rising time of the yellow signal.

Comment: I originally thought rise time as well but notice how my X axis has no shift and notice where my trigger level is. That seems like clear indicators to me that the trigger has fired at t=0. Now it could be propagation delay as I asked but I was hoping for a bit more then a guess like I have.

Comment: Well actually the t=0 thing doesn't matter I guess the scope could just shift the time back in post.